# .htaccess mod_rewrite; new URL are targeting the same file

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /lyrics.php?artist=$1&songname=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /album.php?artist=$1&album=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /artist.php?artist=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know almost anything about mod_rewrite but with tools from the internet I got some of it working. Only problem now is when the user clicks through an album.php address, it think it is for the lyrics.php file. They are colliding. How do I separate them without losing such a "pretty" URL? Down below are mod_rewrite addresses I used and want to become through a generator.

```
    The original URL:
    http://japlyrics.com/lyrics.php?artist=suiyoubi_no_kanpanera&songname=diablo 
    The rewritten URL:
    http://japlyrics.com/suiyoubi_no_kanpanera/diablo.html

    The original URL:
    http://japlyrics.com/album.php?artist=world_order&album=have_a_nice_day
    The rewritten URL: **This one I have issues with.** It think it is for the above URL.
    http://japlyrics.com/world_order/have_a_nice_day.html

    The original URL:
    http://japlyrics.com/artist.php?artist=daoko
    The rewritten URL:
    http://japlyrics.com/daoko.html
```

What should I do?

Comment: You need to add something to distinct both types. For instance, you could add a main subfolder, which could be better (clearer): `/lyrics/ARTIST/SONG-TITLE` and `/album/ARTIST/ALBUM-NAME`. And even better, looking at your links, if i were you, i'd have it that way: `/artist/NAME` , `/artist/NAME/album/ALBUM-NAME` and `/artist/NAME/lyrics/SONG-NAME` (since artist is the main-common component here)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Think I understand. I shall do that!